# How to display and hide an iAd in xCode 5 with storyboards

Tags: xcode5, iad

I have designed a game in Xcode 5 with storyboards and I would like to make it free with iAds displaying on the top. I have heard that I must hide the iAd banner if there is no internet connection or the ad does not load. Unfortunately, I haven't found the code for detecting that. Can someone please help me correct this functionality in my current code?

This is the code I am currently running but it will display a blank space if there is no internet connection. This gives the user a very bad impression of the app.

```
#pragma marks iAd Delegate Methods

-(void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
  [banner setAlpha:1];
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
  [banner setAlpha:0];
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right. We need to hide iAd banner when it doesn't load.

Here's my code.

```
@property BOOL bannerIsVisible;
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    if ( !bannerIsVisible ) {
        banner.alpha = 1.0f;
    }
    bannerIsVisible = YES;
}  
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if ( bannerIsVisible ) {
        banner.alpha = 0.0f;
    }
    bannerIsVisible = NO;
}
```

I hope this helps you.